# Improving phonegap app performance by defining my own WebView

Tags: performance, cordova, webview

i am developing an app in phonegap. I have some performance issues so i want to make my own WebView class and use it instead of the default one.

I found that i can improve performance by doing that, by doing it this way:

https://github.com/ajoslin/angular-mobile-nav/wiki/PhoneGap,-improving-performance

The problem is that i don't know in what class i have to override the init method of the "Activity"
I have tried doing it in the CordovaActivity class but the method init method is different from what the link says. It is this way:

```
public void init() {
        this.init(appView, null, null);
}
```

Can someone help me with where should i put thie code to actually use MyWebView class:

```
CordovaWebView webView = new MyWebView(MyActivity.this);
super.init(webView, new CordovaWebViewClient(this, webView), new CordovaChromeClient(this,webView));
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Yes - try with the CordovaActivity. If it is not that - check the manifest file - for the main activity class name.
Also you will need to import the MyWebView class to the main activity.

```
public void init() {
    CordovaWebView webView = new MyWebView(MyActivity.this);
    super.init(webView, new CordovaWebViewClient(this, webView), new CordovaChromeClient(this,webView));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for replying, but where how should i override the init() method ?

Comment: I have an error in the second line in the part where the init method from the parent class is called. Do you know why?